# Spring: CrossOrigin not working with ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring, cors

There are tons of questions about enabling `CORS` on spring but it seems that not all of those questions have a valid answer or the accepted answer just doesn't work on my case. So i am creating this question to see if anyone could help me.

I've been trying to enable `CORS` response to the responses of my API, i've tried adding `@CrossOrigin` annotation to the method, even to the class controller in order to make it work, but neither of both methods didn't work. I've also tried creating a `Bean` on either the application bootstrap config or a class config that implements `WebMvcConfigurer` but the end result is still the same.

At first i thought it might be because i am returning the response with `ResponseEntity` instance rather than just returning the actual value like most examples show, but even replacing the way i return the value, the result is again the same. No `CORS` headers are appended to the response, not even in `OPTIONS` http method when it's requested, it only responds with normal headers without `Cross Origin Allow`.

So to show how i've been trying to achieve `CORS`, here's one of my `RestController` class:

```
package com.vod.cloudservice.controller;

import com.vod.cloudservice.entity.Series;
import com.vod.cloudservice.service.SeriesService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/series")
public class SeriesController {
    @Autowired
    SeriesService seriesService;

    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Series>> getSeriesList() {
        List<Series> seriesList = this.seriesService.findAll();

        return new ResponseEntity<>(seriesList, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    // More resources ahead.
}
```

Doing this alone didn't work. So i've created a config class like this:

```
package com.vod.cloudservice.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("*")
            .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
            .allowedHeaders("Content-Type")
            .maxAge(3600);
    }
}
```

Even with this, the responses are still the same. and if it helps to know how is the full request to the controller where i want `CORS` to be enabled, the requests are done like this:

```
GET: http://localhost:8080/series
```

I probably work around this by intercepting the response and manually adding the headers, but i'd like to have a better control of the responses, like for instance i want to handle X amount of allowed methods on a class.

Answer (score -1):

I have made even more research on the matter, i've found out that `RestController` annotation makes the response header to be already written at the time when `CORS` annotation is processed, it is as if `CORS` handler cannot write what's being already sent.

So in my case, i created a filter class which will add the `CORS` headers in the response like this:

```
public class HttpFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");

        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }
}
```

After this, i just needed to register the filter as a `FilterBean` and then it works, though not in the way i initially wanted but it atleast gives me the results i need in order to work.

Answer (score -2):

```
allowedHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization, Origin, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your answer.